# Does Control+C delete the files that you were downloading and installing?

Tags: package-management, signals

If you are installing a package in the terminal and you use Control+C to stop it, does it also undo all the changes and remove the files that it downloaded?

Comment: You need to qualify this question further.

Comment: That is completely dependent on the application that you're using to download that package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> (or whatever the current `intr` character is in the output of `stty -a`) in a terminal, if `isig` appears in the output of `stty -a` causes the kernel to send a `SIGINT` signal to every process in the *foreground process group of the terminal*, that is the shell job running in foreground if you're running an interactive shell in that terminal.

By default, that signal causes the process to die straight away (without flushing buffers or any cleanup action). However, applications are free to intercept or ignore that signal and perform whatever action they deem necessary before exiting.

A package manager would typically do so, as it would try and avoid to leave the package system in an inconsistent state. However, all package managers would behave differently, so you'd need to specify which you're using.

Comment: Okay I see, so it's dependent on the package but in most cases it will clean up before cancelling. Like if I were to do sudo apt-install xmbc and then in the middle of the downloading/installing I did CTRL+C it would remove all files?